# Interpreting a Formula Tattoo (Bipolar?)

Tags: organic-chemistry, medicinal-chemistry

[image]

Found This Online. Something to do with bipolar disorder?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! If you could add the details, where you found the formula we can understand the context and maybe give a better answer to your question.

Comment: I found it on a website showing bipolar tattoos/symbols etc. I thought maybe it had to do with Serotonin? Have zero knowledge of chemistry, so i thought i would ask some people who do!

Answer (score 8):

This is [lamotrigine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamotrigine), a sodium channel blocker prescribed against epilepsy.  Apparently it's also prescribed for bipolar disorder.